Correlation of predictMemUsage and maxSegmentSize for collection that has 1 shard, 1000+ partitions
We have seen predictMemUsage and maxSegmentSize error oftening coming. Can you shed some light on the error ? If a collection has 1 shard, 1000+ partitions,  1 bn+ data volume. and we see below error, what could be the possible reason ?
error="load segment failed, OOM if load, maxSegmentSize = 1088.1805419921875 MB,  memUsage = 236218.07943725586 MB, predictMemUsage = 237306.25997924805 MB, totalMem = 245760 MB thresholdFactor = 0.900000"]

querycoord.
Importantly, how to ensure that predictMemUsage is always less than maxSegmentSize ?
